# How I can use std::max_element for a struct

Tags: c++

I want use `std::max_element` for the struct `VAR_T` based on the `id` element,
but I can't link start and stop point with inputs of this function.

```
typedef struct _VAR_ {
  int id;
  char b[16];

  _VAR_() {
    int a = 0;
    strcpy (b, "------");
  }
} VAR_T;

VAR_T newVar[5];
int counter;
int max

max = *std::max_element (newVar.id, newVar.id + counter);
```

This error is issued in the last line:

> error: request for member ‘id’

Comment: Don't use `typedef struct { } xxx;` in C++.  Just use `struct xxx { };`.

Comment: sorry, id is a member of struct newVar,I corrected it

Comment: I think you can't do `_VAR_` because underscores followed by an upper case are not allowed. See `17.6.3.3.2 Global names [global.names]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a custom comparator to compare based on the `id` member.  Then, you need to retrieve the `id` member:

```
auto it = std::max_element(newVar, newVar + counter,
                           [](const VAR_T& lhs, const VAR_T& rhs)
                           { return lhs.id < rhs.id; })
int max = it->id;
```

Since C++20, you can also use projections:

```
ranges::max_element(newVar, ranges::less, &VAR_T::id);
```

Comment: thank you, I'm trying it out. can i use this statement  for memmove ?

Comment: @Baharmast Well, how exactly do you want to move?

Comment: for example move in "id" in "newVar".

Comment: @Baharmast Well, no.  The `mem*` family of functions deal with memory, and they know nothing about your data structure.  You can use `std::copy` instead.